# Set startup file in PHP Server cpanel

Tags: php, server, cpanel

I am dot net developer. I place `web.config and index.html` page and write some code in `web.config.` it opens the index.html default or startup page when I enter my website address in the browser.

Now my question is here, I have PHP cPanel and domain, I want to place `index.html`  page and open it as a startup page. but I found an irrelevant solution according to my problem statement.
How can I do this?

I tried, I placed the `index.html page` in `public_html` but the page did not open.

any solution, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the web server you are using?

If you are using Apache or Nginx, it should load the index.html as default (Start) page. Make sure, you have the index.html in the web root directory.

Comment: It is apache. and i added index.html. but it is not loading.

Comment: Seems your domain is not pointed to the correct document root folder? If you want to force your apache to load index,html by default, you can do it using .htacces file.

Create a .htaccess file in your document root folder and add the following line to the that file.

DirectoryIndex index.html

For more details - http://www.htaccess-guide.com/directoryindex-uses/

Answer (score 0):

Please, this code in `web.config` file in the `public_html` folder.

```
<system.webServer>
         <defaultDocument>
                <files>
                    <clear />               
                    <add value="index.html"/>
                </files>
        </defaultDocument>
    </system.webServer>
```

You can also set a priority of files execution in `web.config` file as:

```
<add value="Default.htm" />
<add value="Default.asp" />
 <add value="index.htm" />
 <add value="index.html" />
 <add value="iisstart.htm" />
 <add value="default.aspx" />
 <add value="index.php" />
```

Comment: Will it work for php too?
Because i think, web.config file is used in dot net. can we use it in php?

Comment: @FaseehHaris, Okay sure